# Intermittent issues with multiple logical operators in conditional statements using Python

Tags: python

I have an issue where a conditional statement is triggered even if all the conditions arent met.

for example, in this code

```
        if (
            (time_up_fmt <= clock_fmt <= buffer_up) and
            (lux_src >= light_sw and
            lux_src != 999999) and
            ("Down" == last_action)
            or
            (approx_up_min <= clock_fmt <= approx_up_max) and
            ("Down" == last_action)
    ):

        print("going up")
```

The above condition is sometimes triggered even if the lux_src is 6 and light_sw is 50. It should only be triggered is lux_src is 50 or above

I believe operators precedence are correct.

Any idea how I can troubleshoot this?

the full script is [here](https://edube.org/sandbox/69b524d2-4dbe-11eb-b49e-024250c4691c)

thank you

Answer (score 0):

A = (time_up_fmt <= clock_fmt <= buffer_up)

B = (lux_src >= light_sw and lux_src != 999999)

C = ("Down" == last_action)

D = (approx_up_min <= clock_fmt <= approx_up_max)

E = ("Down" == last_action)

```
    A         B         C        D        E
>>> False and False and False or True and True
True
```

So, even if the lux_src is 6 and light_sw is 50 (B evaluates to False), the overall condition can evaluate to True.

Comment: Why are you saying that C is false and D is true?

Comment: What I am saying is, as per your description, there is a POSSIBILITY that the whole expression can evaluate to true. I would encourage you to check condition by specifying real values in place of the variables.

Comment: Also, according to values in your script, I don't think it goes inside 'if' block. If you still find an unexpected case, post the values for all variables.That would help us understand what's happening.

Comment: i put a link to the full script in the question. cant you access it?

Answer (score -1):

maybe the second part of the if statement the "or" part is triggering the True condition

Comment: i dont think so, the second part approx_up_min <= clock_fmt <= approx_up_max would be 08:25:00 <= 07:47:15 <= 08:35:00

Comment: try to print that second part and see if it evaluates to False

Comment: print((approx_up_min <= clock_fmt <= approx_up_max)) returns False